# javascript error "e" undefined when calling e.preventDefault()

Tags: javascript, jquery, object, undefined, preventdefault

I didn't write this code and I'm having trouble figuring out why I'm getting the following the error at the first `e.preventDefault()`.  I've tried moving that code around within the `.click` event handler, passing it to `function(e){}`, replacing it with `return false`, declaring it `var e = $(this.href)` (don't laugh, I'm trying to learn), I've checked the value being returned in the `a href` and it is returning the correct `hash`.  The video plays, but I'm getting this error when I run the IE debugger.   Would someone please tell me how to properly debug and fix this.  Thanks

[image]

HTML

```
 <a href="#video1" class="blueBtn modal" style="width:150px;"><span>Watch Video <img width="10" height="17" src="images/bluebtn.png"></span></a></div>
```

Javascript

```
// FANCY BOX
$("a.modal").click(function(){
    var inline=$(this).attr('href');
    $.fancybox({
        'transitionIn'      : 'none',
        'transitionOut'     : 'none',
        'href'              : inline,
        'onComplete'        : function(){
            $(inline+' .flowPlayer').videoPlayer();
            $.fancybox.center(true);
        },
        'onClosed'          : function(){loc();}
    });
    e.preventDefault();         
});

$(".print").click(function(e){
    window.open("print-docs/"+$(this).parent().attr('id')+".html","print","width=1,height=1");
    e.preventDefault();
});

function loc(){
    var location=window.location.href;
    var replaceHash=location.replace(document.location.hash,"");
    window.location.assign(replaceHash);
}
```

Comment: Read the docs: http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/. When you compare your code to the example, you'll see that you're obviously missing something.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Should be

```
$("a.modal").click(function(e) { // Note the "e" parameter
    // etc
});
```

... instead, just like in the second click handler. See, both these functions are supplied with the [jQuery Event object](http://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/) (a wrapper around native [Event object](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Events/events.html#Events-Event)) as a first parameter. But you still have to let JavaScript know how exactly this parameter will be referred to in your function. )

Comment: Thanks. That was the first thing I tried, however, the video freezes in the browser now.  I don't know, maybe it's because I'm testing the code locally on my laptop and not on the testing server that is reporting the error?  I'll just send that revision to the backend folks and see if when they push it to staging, the error won't occur nor will the video freeze.

Comment: I find this line a bit suspicious too: `$(inline+' .flowPlayer').videoPlayer();` Could you elaborate more on that topic - in a separate question, perhaps?

Comment: sure @raina77ow. I didn't write the code but... EDIT creating a new thread with the code

Answer (score 3):

You need to add the `e` parameter yourself:

```
$("a.modal").click(function(e){  //<------- right there
    var inline=$(this).attr('href');
    $.fancybox({
        'transitionIn'      : 'none',
        'transitionOut'     : 'none',
        'href'              : inline,
        'onComplete'        : function(){
            $(inline+' .flowPlayer').videoPlayer();
            $.fancybox.center(true);
        },
        'onClosed'          : function(){loc();}
    });
    e.preventDefault();         
});
```

Comment: thanks.  I tried that first, but the video freezes in the browser.

Comment: @Chris - not sure why it froze your window - you must have something else going on.  But that's definitely the way to pass the event object into your handler

Comment: +1 @Adam. Thanks that's what I thought -- there must be something else going on...

Answer (score 2):

You missed the `e` parameter:

```
$("a.modal").click(function(e){

   e.preventDefault();  
}
```